# mongoose find two ids in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Assuming the following schema:

```
  participants: [{
    user: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
    },
    active: Boolean
  }]
```

with:

```
participants: [{
    "user": {
        "$oid": "5731ffe827b3453707f742a3"
    },
    "active": true,
}, {
    "user": {
        "$oid": "5731ffe827b3453707f742a4"
    },
    "active": true,
}]
```

what's the best way to find participants user ?
To find one participant user is easy. Just findOne('participants.user': _id).

But i want to find : 'participants.user': _id **and** 'participants.user': _id
The Participants Array must contains both user id's.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a thing called `$or` that allows you to find different users.

example:

```
find( { $or:[ {'_id':myId}, {'name':name}, {'nickname':nick} ]}
```